# Ktor - kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ClosedReceiveChannelException: Channel was closed

Tags: kotlin, server, httpclient, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I am receiving back this `kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ClosedReceiveChannelException` upon about 50% of my api calls to a post url through Ktor `HttpClient`.

Our code looks like

`Module.kt`

```
bind<ServiceClient>() with singleton {
    val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
        install(JsonFeature) {
            serializer = KotlinxSerializer()
        }
    }
    ServiceClient( client, instance() )
}
```

and our implementation of the call is

```
suspend fun post(request: RequestObject): List<ResponseObjects> =
    client.post(endpoint) {
        contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
        body = request

    }
```

Sometimes I am able to receive back the expected results and other times I get the client closed exception. What am I doing wrong here?

I am on Ktor version 1.6.4

Comment: Does it happen with any URL or only with a certain one?

Comment: Could you please share a full stack trace of an error?

Comment: Is this error specific for `CIO` engine? Or for [others](https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-engines.html#jvm-android) as well?